# Laravel 3 table Eloquent: relation

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, relation

I have 3 tables

***roles***

id `````` |```` `` role    ```````` |

1     `````` ```````` Staff

***permissions***

id ````````|     ``````````     Name  ````````````   |

1   ````````````Manage All Projects

2  ```````````` Manage Clients

***acces_permissions***

id_permission  FK  | id_role   FK
`````` `` 1  ````````````````````              1

````````      2     ````````````````````           1

and i will have a table with

roles |     permissions Name      |

Staff |  Manage All Projects  Manage Clients |

how can o this whit this 3 Models

```
class roles extends Model
class permissions extends Model
class acces_permissions extends Model
```

Comment: please be more specific with your question. what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Is this question regarding laravel 3 or regarding laravel and 3 tables?

Comment: question regarding laravel 5.6

Comment: i will get all permissions using the role of a user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct me if im wrong, what you are trying to achieve is get all permissions using the role of a user ..

the easiest way is to use `belongsToMany` eloquent relation, in your Role model add this

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permissions', 'access_permission_table', 'id_role', 'id_permission');
}
```

this way, when you call $role->permissions, you'll get all the permission for that role.

Comment: yep i will get all permissions using the role of a user

Answer (score 0):

i put

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('permissions::class', 'access_permissions', 
    'id_role', 'id_permission');
}
```

in  class roles extends Model

get

```
$roles=roles::all();
```

in controller

and

```
@foreach($roles as $role)
$role['permissions']
```

in templete

but dosent work

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'mycrm.access_permissions' doesn't exist (SQL: select `permissions`.*, 
`access_permissions`.`id_role` as `pivot_id_role`, 
`access_permissions`.`id_permission` as `pivot_id_permission` from 
`permissions` inner join `access_permissions` on `permissions`.`id` = 
`access_permissions`.`id_permission` where `access_permissions`.`id_role` = 
1) (View: 
F:\MYCRM\mycrm\packages\tc\calculator\src\views\permission_pack.blade.php)
```

but the join query seems right

Answer (score 0):

ok i did

```
public function permissions()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany(permissions::class, 'acces_permissions' , 'id_role', 
 'id_permission');
}
```

and now it work differently of before i dont know why